# Javascript not loading onClick validate form before loading php page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a piece of HTML and JavaScript code and I need to check if inputs have been filled before clicking the button. However, when I leave them blank, it proceeds to the php page passing the variables empty.
I have made some tests and I've concluded it does not load the onClick function at all.
This is the code (without all the CSS stuff):

```
      <div class = "register">
    <form action = "register.php" method = "post" name = "reg1" id = "register" onClick = "return validateForm();">
      <input type = "text" class = "reg" id = "name" name = "name"/>
       <div class = "alert" id = "inserthere1"> </div>
      <input type = "text" class = "reg" id = "surname" name = "surname"/> <div class = "alert" id = "inserthere2"></div>
      <input type = "text" class = "reg" id = "mail" name = "mail" /><div class = "alert" id = "inserthere3"></div>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Join!" >
      </form>
    </div>

  <script language = "JavaScript">
    function validateForm() {
      var n = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var c = document.getElementById("surname").value;
      var m = document.getElementById("mail").value;
      alert("Nome:"+n+"Cognome:"+c+"Mail:"+m);
      document.getElementById("inserthere1").innerHTML = (n===null || n==="" ? '<i> This cannot be left empty. </i>' : '');
      document.getElementById("inserthere2").innerHTML = (c===null || c==="" ? '<i> This cannot be left empty. </i>' : '');
      document.getElementById("inserthere3").innerHTML = (m===null || m==="" ? '<i> This cannot be left empty. </i>' : '');
      if ( n===null || c===null || n==="" || c==="" || m===null || m==="" )
        return false;
        }
      return true;
      }
```

Comment: Before you write about it: the </script> is present in the current code.

Comment: It seems that you've forgotten some curly braces...https://jsfiddle.net/ap88x7a8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to make sure the fields are filled in before proceeding? You can use:

```
<input required="">
```

This way the user has to fill out the fields with **required=""**, or their browser won't let them submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **preventDefault** on the submit event or use a button instead a input, after that you have to use the onclick event on the button, not into the form that will validate if the inputs has been filled or not.

After you validate the form you can use this for submit your form

`document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`

That will send the form data to the action script.

Ref: [preventDefault Documentation | W3CSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Ref2: [Form Submit method | W3CSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<form>..</form>
document.addEventListener('click', validateForm, false);
<script language = "JavaScript">
   function validateForm() {
     ..
</script>
```